# How do I run LibGDX's Particle Editor in Netbeans?

Tags: java, libgdx, particles

I am trying to run the Particle Editor that comes with LibGDX in Netbeans.  The `gdx-tools-1.9.10.jar` file shows up in my dependencies, and I can see all of the packages and class files inside it:

[image: gdx-tools-1.9.10.jar]

Normally, when I want to run a file, I open the file by double-clicking it in the "Projects" panel, right click anywhere in the file, and then click the "Run File" option.  However, when I use the same process to try to run a class file in gdx-tools, the "Run File" option appears to be grayed out:

[image: Run File (Shift+F6)]

I have also tried using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> shortcut, with no effect.  Just as a sanity check, I did also make sure that the class file I am trying to run has a `main` method:

[image: main method]

I have also tried running the Particle Editor from the command line (I'm using Windows).  I navigated to the gdx-tools directory using the following command:

```
cd C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-tools\1.9.10\<hash>
```

I then tried to run the Particle Editor using the following command:

```
java -cp gdx-tools-1.9.10.jar com.badlogic.gdx.tools.particleeditor.ParticleEditor.class
```

And the result is simply:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.badlogic.gdx.tools.particleeditor.ParticleEditor.class
```

How do I run the Particle Editor?  I would prefer to be able to run it in Netbeans, but I would be happy to get it to run at all.  I am using LibGDX 1.9.10, Netbeans 8.2, and Java (JDK and JRE) 8u111 on Windows 10.  I installed LibGDX using their setup app found [here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html).